# Errores de búsqueda en la base de datos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito que en la vista `index` se digite en un campo de texto el número de cédula de una persona que deseo consultar. Cuando la digite y pulse el botón "Consultar", me lleve a la vista `show` donde se mostrarán todos los cursos que esa persona ha realizado: puede ser uno, dos o más. En el código que les relaciono a continuación sólo me está mostrando la información de una sola persona, porque tengo esta línea de código en el controlador `@ccconsultar = "1066572739"`, pero obviamente necesito que la cédula que se digite en la vista `index` sea la que se muestre en la vista `show`. Pienso que el problema radica a la hora de capturar la variable.

CONTROLADOR "ESTUDIANTE"

```
class EstudiantesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @ccconsultar = "1066572739"
    @e = Estudiante.where(:cedula => @ccconsultar)
  end

private
  def estudiante_params
    params.require(:estudiante).permit(:id_certificado, :cedula, :nombre, :apellidos, :nivel, :fecha, :url)
  end
end
```

CONFIGURACIÓN DE RUTAS

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'estudiantes#index'
  get 'estudiantes/new'
  get 'estudiantes/show'
  get 'estudiantes/show_null'
end
```

VISTA INDEX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Consulta de Certificados</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">CONSULTA DE CERTIFICADOS</h1>
    <p></p>
    <%= form_tag("/estudiantes/show", method: "get") do %>
      <div class="text-center"><h3>Digite la cédula a consultar:</h3></div>
      <%= label_tag(@ccconsultar, "") %>
      <div align="center"><%= text_field_tag(@ccconsultar) %></div><br>
      <div align="center"><%= submit_tag("Consultar") %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</body>
```

VISTA SHOW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Consulta de Certificados</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Información de los Cursos Realizados</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Cedula</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Nivel</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Descargar</th>
      </tr>
      <% @e.each do |f| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.id_certificado %></td>
        <td><%= f.cedula %></td>
        <td><%= f.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= f.apellidos %></td>
        <td><%= f.nivel %></td>
        <td><%= f.fecha %></td>
        <td><a href="<%= f.url %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Descargar</a></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div align="center"><a href="/" button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Regresar</a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está en que no estás asignando un valor para tu [text_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag).
De acuerdo a la documentación, el primer parámetro es el nombre del campo y el segundo sería el valor (que al parecer no sería necesario agregarlo, ya que es un campo de búsqueda).
Por lo tanto, en tu index podrías reemplazar  `text_field_tag(@ccconsultar)` por algo como:

```
<div align="center"><%= text_field_tag(:cedula) %></div><br>
```

Luego, si tus registros son únicos (cada registro en la tabla de estudiantes tiene una única cédula), cambia tu `where` por `find_by` para que te retorne un único estudiante.

```
@e = Estudiante.find_by(cedula: params[:cedula])
```

Esto implica que cambies la vista show para que solo muestre ese registro y luego iterar sobre los cursos que tenga asociado ese estudiante (remover el `@e.each` y en vez, hacer la iteración sobre el modelo de cursos asociado a tu estudiante).
Si por el contrario, cada registro en la tabla de estudiantes también guarda los cursos que tiene ese estudiante, habiendo múltiples registros de un mismo estudiante, pero con distintos cursos, deja tu vista tal como está y cambia el `where` por:

```
@e = Estudiante.where(cedula: params[:cedula])
```

Si la segunda es tu opción, te sugiero que cambies tu diseño de las tablas. Creo que es incorrecto y tal cual explicas en tu pregunta, un estudiante puede tener muchos cursos, eso implica dos tablas y una relación `has_many` en tu modelo `Estudiante`, pero bueno... no conozco en detalle cual es tu implementación, puedes tener tus razones para haberlo hecho de esa forma, aparte que eso ya es parte de otro potencial problema que escapa del alcance de esta pregunta.

Comment: Mil gracias. Pero realicé las modificaciones tal cual como me las sugeriste y al realizar la consulta en el `index`, cuando presioné el botón de buscar, me llevó a un error donde dice `undefined method each for #<Estudiante:0x000000000e5001f0>`. Me podrías ayudar con ello, por fa...
Como dato adicional, me gustaría resaltar que en el log, en esta ocasión, sí realizó la consulta, sólo que ahora no reconoce la lista. Cabe recordar que podrían traer uno, dos o más registros en la vista show... Tiene algo que ver?

Comment: @AlvaroAndresHernandez por eso te especificaba en el último punto, debí haberlo explicado de otra manera. He actualizado la respuesta a ver si se entiende mejor.

Comment: Excelente, @Alter-Lagos!. Hice las últimas correcciones de la lista de tus sugerencias y se corrigió el problema. De verdad, mil gracias!